# Can BitTorrent Sync CLI be used to create shares?

Tags: command-line, bittorrent-sync

[BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) can be executed from command line, but there are only a few options show by the `--help` parameter. Executing `btsync` makes a web ui available (at port 8888) which can be used to configure.

```
BitTorrent Sync 1.2.73
Usage:
      btsync [--config <path>] [--nodaemon] [--generate-secret] [--dump-sample-config] [--help] [--get-ro-secret <secret>]
Options:
    --config - location and name of configuration file
    --nodaemon - do not use daemon mode
    --generate-secret - generate shared secret
    --get-ro-secret - get read only secret for existing master secret
    --dump-sample-config - dump sample config file
    --help - print this message and exit
```

These options don't seem to include creating a new shared folder.

**Can I create a new share with BitTorrent Sync using only command line?**

I'm also interested in even very hacky solutions, like editing the config file and restarting the service, or posting specific HTTP requests to localhost:8888.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to use the config file for this.

You can use `btsync --dump-sample-config` (or `--get-sample-config` if you are using an older version) to get a sample, feed it the necessary paths under "shared folders" and secrets generated by `--generate` a secret.

Then save the config file then tell btsync to use that config file by launching it with `--config`.

You can find all this in [page 10 of this version of the manual](http://web.archive.org/web/20140811214758/http://btsync.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BitTorrentSyncUserGuide.pdf). Note that this will disable the web UI.

I leave it as an exercise for the user to script all this in whatever hacky way his heart desire.

Comment: Yes, this works. And it's even pretty easy to automatically edit the config file since it's in JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Is it real JSON? I have the impression it isn't. JSON has no comments right?

Comment: The link of manual is off

Comment: Lucky the answer is self contained. Updated to a way back machine link that should have the same information